# Md-Sidenav. How can i push main content to the right when sidenav is open?

Tags: angular-material

So I learning by building a portfolio SPA and I really want to use md-sidenav and so far it works but its showing up above my content and i want it to just push my content to the right when it's opened.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
  $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
  };
});
```

HTML

```
 <div layout="row" ng-controller="MyController">
              <!--MENU ICON AND FUNCTION  -->
<md-button ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
  <a><i class="material-icons medium">menu</i></a>
</md-button>




              <md-sidenav  md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" style="background-color: white;" >

                    <div class="container" style="    margin-top: 30px;
                width: 90%;">
                          <img class="circle  responsive-img ram " src="assets/avatar.png" style="margin-left: 13%">
                          <p style="font-weight:bold;
                          text-decoration:underline;color:#FF5E19;
                          letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;
                          font-size:18px;text-align:center;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                          line-height:1;">Ramin Joseph</p>



                     </div>
                     <div class="nav-wrapper">
                     <div class="col l12 s12 m12">
                    <ul style=" text-align:center;">
                      <li class="sbar"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                      <li class="sbar"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                      <li class="sbar"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                      <li class="sbar"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>    

              </md-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute `md-is-locked-open` on `md-sidenav` element.

However, then you'll have to change the logic how to open the sidenav. I would do it by binding `md-is-locked-open` to the model state property and then toggling it myself on click event:

```
<md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="isSideNavOpen">...</md-sidenav>

$scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
  $scope.isSideNavOpen = !$scope.isSideNavOpen;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For new Angular Material version

Add `mode="push"` in your `<md-sidenav>.`

```
<md-sidenav mode="push">

</md-sidenav>
```

Refer this : [Sidenave | Angular Material | Mode](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#sidenav-mode)